# understanding for in angular loop in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I was just going through this example online of $watch in angular and basically came across this weird syntax below:

```
       <select ng-model="countSelection" ng-options="n for n in [5,10,15,20]"></select>
```

Now i am familiar with the `for ..in` loop, in native javascript , but what the heck is `ng-options="n for n in [5,10,15,20]"` ? can anybody explain this ? I have seen the documentation **[HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)** , there are a few similar examples , but nothing quite the same, and i quite puzzled by that syntax, can anybody explain ?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the proper documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Please follow-up your questions by either accepting an answer or commenting on them to clarify why you haven't accepted any answer yet.

Comment: There is no time frame for accepting an answer. don't get desperate for your answer to be accepted. this question is going nowhere and is open for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's not JavaScript, it's a repeat expression that is specific to AngularJS. Here's the definition from the documentation:

> The expression indicating how to enumerate a collection.

There are various formats for repeat expressions. AngularJS compiler is able to parse them and provide variables for a loop scope.

Comment: can you provide a documentation link or an example . thanks

Comment: @TenaliRaman It's on the page you posted. Scroll down to the arguments section.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that it can easily be used to iterate over an array of objects based on a particular key. Say you have the following data:

```
$scope.arr = [
    {'key1': 1, 'key2': 4},
    {'key1': 2, 'key2': 5}
]
```

Now, in your markup you can either iterate over `key1`:

```
<select ng-model="temp" ng-options="n.key1 for n in arr">

</select>
```

or over `key2`

```
<select ng-model="temp" ng-options="n.key2 for n in arr">

</select>
```

This ensures your `ng-model` holds on to the right key's value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is tricky and specific implementation of ngOptions for dropdowns, actually, it is documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Long story short: you have an array, and you should tell Angular, what it should pass as value for those options.
For example, you have array of objects:

```
myArr = [{id:1, description:'First'}, {id:2, description:'Second'}, ...]
```

So if you want to use field ID as a value for select options, you can create the following select:

```
<select ng-model="countSelection" ng-options="obj.id for obj in myArr"></select>
```

That's it! In your case, you have the array of numbers, and you want to use this numbers as value for your options. So we can translate this line **ng-options="n for n in [5,10,15,20]"** as following:

*Please, take every element of the array, and call it 'n'. And please use this 'n' as a value for my options.*